# Basic question: How to solve the following $2 \times 2$ (block-based) linear system analytically?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for asking basic question, but I think I have some trouble in understanding the below part. Please excuse me for asking trivial question.

Say $2 \times 2$ linear system is 
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
H &  A^T  \\
A &  0
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x  \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
b  \\
c 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
$H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a non-singular matrix, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} $, the unknowns $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} $, and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} $.

Then solve for $x$ and $y$ based on
\begin{align}
A H^{-1} A^T y &= -c + AH^{-1}b \\
H x &= b - A^Ty \ .
\end{align}

**Question**: 
How to reach to those two system of equations?

Comment: Could you give us some context?  Where did you encounter this?  Do you understand that the system can be rewritten as 
$$
Hx + A^Ty = b\\
Ax = c?
$$

Comment: I Think I understand the matrix vector Products. Yes, I found this on page 12 of this slidekit https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/11EqualityMin.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use block-wise row-operations.  That is:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
 H&A^T & b\\A&0&c
\end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
 I& H^{-1}A^T & H^{-1}b\\A&0&c
\end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
 I& H^{-1}A^T & H^{-1}b\\
0&-AH^{-1}A^T & c - AH^{-1}b
\end{array}\right]
$$
which leaves us with the system of equations
$$
x + H^{-1}A^Ty = H^{-1}b\\
-AHA^Ty = c - AH^{-1}b
$$

Comment: I think this is what they mean by "elimination".  The step of multiplying the first row by $H^{-1}$ is not necessary, strictly speaking

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The system reads
$$
Hx + A^T y = b, \\Ax = c
$$

If matrix $A$ was invertible, this would a trivial problem, since from the second equation we would have $x = A^{-1} c$ and the 1st equation would simply become $H A^{-1}c + A^{T}y = b \Leftrightarrow y = A^{-T}(b-H A^{T}c)$. However, this is not the case... So we must manipulate the equations in such a way that we are able to isolate x and y. We are allowed to use $H^{-1}$, but not $A^{-1}$ or $A^{-T}$.

Taking the 1st equation, you get $x=H^{-1}(b-A^{T}y)$. Substituting x in the second equation, you get $A H^{-1}(b-A^{T}y) = c \Leftrightarrow A H^{-1} A^{T} y = -c + A H^{-1} b $. Hope it helps!